# Quick PHP Variable guidance

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables, include

I'm a newbie with PHP. I am trying to create a log in /register system for a project, so I am using a login system source code I found which has many functions and features like salted passwords. The system itself works fine, but I am trying to add more fields to my MySQL Table. The system had an array for extra columns, but I think it was resulting in bad mysql syntax so I decided to write out the query myself using the variables, but I am not sure how I can give access to the variables to the function. The variables are in the register.php document, here is the code (all of register.php):

```
        if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $user    = $_POST['username'];
            $sex = $_POST['sex'];
            $country = $_POST['strCountryChoice'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $pass    = $_POST['pass'];
            $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
            $birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
            $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            //need to add a lot more validation functions.. AKA Check if email exists and username. Password > 5 chars
            if( $user=="" || $email=="" || $pass=='' || $pass2=='' || $firstname=='' || $lastname='' || $sex='' || $country='' || $birthdate='' ){
                echo "Fields Left Blank","Some Fields were left blank. Please fill up all fields.";
                exit;
            }
            if( !$LS->validEmail($email) ){
                echo "E-Mail Is Not Valid", "The E-Mail you gave is not valid";
                exit;
            }
            if( !ctype_alnum($user) ){
                echo "Invalid Username", "The Username is not valid. Only ALPHANUMERIC characters are allowed and shouldn't exceed 10 characters.";
                exit;
            }
            if($pass != $pass2){
                echo "Passwords Don't Match","The Passwords you entered didn't match";
                exit;
            }
        $createAccount = $LS->register($user, $pass,
                array(
                    "email"      => $email,
                    "name"   => $firstname,
                    "lastname" => $lastname,
                    "gender" => $sex,
                    "country" => $country,
                    "DOB" => $birthdate,
                    "created" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") // Just for testing

                )
            );
            if($createAccount === "exists"){
                echo "User Exists.";
            }elseif($createAccount === true){
                echo "Success. Created account.";
            }
    }
```

The whole system takes place in another file which has the class. Here is the register function:

```
public function register( $id, $password, $other = array() ){
    if( $this->userExists($id) && (isset($other['email']) && $this->userExists($other['email'])) ){
        return "exists";
    }else{
        $randomSalt = $this->rand_string(20);
        $saltedPass = hash('sha256', "{$password}{$this->passwordSalt}{$randomSalt}");

        if( count($other) == 0 ){
            /* If there is no other fields mentioned, make the default query */
            //old query: ("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, `password`, `password_salt`) VALUES(:username, :password, :passwordSalt)");
            //new query: ("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, 'email' , `password`, `password_salt` , 'name' , 'lastname' , 'gender' , 'country' , 'DOB') VALUES(:username, :email, :pass, :passwordSalt, :firstname, :lastname, :gender, :country, :DOB)");
            $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, `password`, `password_salt`) VALUES(:username, :password, :passwordSalt)");
        }else{
            /* if there are other fields to add value to, make the query and bind values according to it */
            //old query: ("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, `password`, `password_salt`, $columns) VALUES(:username, :password, :passwordSalt, :$colVals)");
            //new query: ("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, 'email' , `password`, `password_salt` , 'name' , 'lastname' , 'gender' , 'country' , 'DOB') VALUES(:username, :email, :pass, :passwordSalt, :firstname, :lastname, :gender, :country, :DOB)");
            $keys    = array_keys($other);
            $columns = implode(",", $keys);
            $colVals = implode(",:", $keys);
        //l= $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, `password`, `password_salt`, $columns) VALUES(:username, :password, :passwordSalt, :$colVals)");
            //INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)cLUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')
            $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (username,email,password,password_salt,name,lastname,created,gender,country,DOB) VALUES ('$username','$email','$pass','$saltedPass','$firstname','$lastname','$created','$gender','$country','$birthdate')");
            print($sql);
            foreach($other as $key => $value){
                $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
                $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
            }
        }
        /* Bind the default values */
        $sql->bindValue(":username", $id);
        $sql->bindValue(":password", $saltedPass);
        $sql->bindValue(":passwordSalt", $randomSalt);
        $sql->execute();
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I need to use the variables from register.php in the class file. Can I just include it at the top or do I need to do something specific to the function?

Thanks. I'm focusing on the $sql line after else.

Comment: "I'm new to PHP, I'm writing a login system." **DON'T**. Please. Stop right there. These are very hard to get right, and if done wrong have the opposite effect on security. Modern PHP development encourages using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that comes with an [authentication layer](http://laravel.com/docs/security) that works out of the box. There is absolutely no reason to write your own unless you've tried all the others and found them inadequate.

Comment: Thanks for info. Well I'm not really that new to PHP, but I thought the question was a basic one. Also I was using someone's source code as I knew I wouldn't be able to write a fully secure login system myself. I am actually trying to create a PHP-Based game which uses profiles in database and lots of other things. I was just going to create the login system with this, then code the landing page and all of aspects myself in PHP, would you recommend me to do it this way or use a development framework? This isn't task, it's just a hobby I want to take up in my free time.

Comment: I've heard from a lot of people that Laravel, as one example, is really easy to pick up on and very pleasant to work with. If you're doing this as a hobby and you don't want to get mired in low-level PHP, a framework is the way to go. Most have a large library of already written community code you can just add on instead of having to write it yourself. You'll be far more productive with a good framework than without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can include/require register.php file in the class file to use all the variables.

On another note i would like to mention that you should always filter out the POST data before adding it to the query for security concerns.

Comment: Hi, I have added include "register.php" in the class file, But now I am getting an out of memory error? Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ls\register.php on line 20

I am unsure why I am getting the error as I believe register.php isn't overwriting any variables.
Thanks again.

Comment: apart from variables is there any other code in register.php file?

Comment: There is some HTML, assuming you don't need this. I have some PHP code at the top which is including another file config.php which starts the system class. I'll add the rest of register in main post.

Comment: condition checking is not correct for all the variables after $firstname. you need to compare using double equals sign (==) rather than single equals=, update your condition first
if( $user=="" || $email=="" || $pass=='' || $pass2=='' || $firstname=='' || $lastname=='' || $sex=='' || $country=='' || $birthdate=='' ){

Comment: Okay I corrected that, I am still getting the memory error :(
Thanks again.